# Spring cloud stream kafka pause/resume binders

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, circuit-breaker

We are using spring cloude stream **2.0** & Kafka as a message broker.
We've implemented a circuit breaker which stops the Application context, for cases where the target system (DB or 3rd party API) is unavilable, as suggested here: [Stop Spring Cloud Stream @StreamListener from listening when target system is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598943/stop-spring-cloud-stream-streamlistener-from-listening-when-target-system-is-do)

Now in spring cloud stream 2.0 there is a way to manage the lifecycle of binder using actuator: [Binding visualization and control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_binding_visualization_and_control)

Is it possible to control the binder lifecycle from the code, means in case target server is down, to `pause` the binder, and when it's up, to `resume`?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I misread your question.

You can auto wire the `BindingsEndpoint` but, unfortunately, its `State` enum is private so you can't call `changeState()` programmatically.

I have [opened an issue for this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1540).

**EDIT**

You can do it with reflection, but it's a bit ugly...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So53476384Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53476384Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    BindingsEndpoint binding;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.forName("org.springframework.cloud.stream.endpoint.BindingsEndpoint$State",
                    So53476384Application.class.getClassLoader());
            ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(BindingsEndpoint.class, method -> {
                try {
                    method.invoke(this.binding, "input", clazz.getEnumConstants()[2]); // PAUSE
                }
                catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, method -> method.getName().equals("changeState"));
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

}
```

Comment: We can change it with reflaction as a WA?