# How to implement a Kafka consumer to process events on demand using spring-cloud-stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement a PollableConsumer that starts polling messages from Kafka under a certain condition, in this case, when I hit an endpoint in my SpringBoot app.

I tried multiple ways of triggering the poller under a certain condition but apparently it only works if it is constantly polling from the kafka topic. (like all the examples in the spring-cloud-stream docs)

I am looking for something like this:

```java
public interface CustomProcessor {
    @Input
    PollableMessageSource input();
}
```

```java
 public void run() {
        boolean result = true;
        while (result) {
            result = input.poll(m -> {
                Event event = (Event) m.getPayload();
                GenericMessage<Event> genericMessage = new GenericMessage<>(event, m.getHeaders());
                eventMessageConsumer.consume(genericMessage);
            }, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Event>() {
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Success");
            }
        }
    }
```

That could be triggered when I hit a endpoint like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/process")
public void process() {
   SomeClass.run();
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure I fully understand what you mean when you say ". . .but apparently it only works if it is constantly polling. . .". Is it possible for you to push your sample to GitHub so we can take a look?

Comment: You have to continually poll so that Kafka keeps the consumer alive; if you don't keep polling, kafka will perform a rebalance. I think we need to add pause/resume to the pollable source (and the underlying SIK KafkaMessageSource) so you can poll continually but control whether or not records will be retrieved by the poll. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/issues/259

Comment: That would be great @GaryRussell. I just found in the docs we can use actuator to have similar behavior by pausing the Binder:
curl -d '{"state":"PAUSED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST <host>:<port>/actuator/bindings/myBindingName

Is there a way to start the springboot app with the binder paused?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, I will try to perform some clean up in the code and share with you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to pause a PollableConsumer at the moment using spring-cloud-stream, so I moved back to event-based based message consumption and used actuator to control the state of the binding. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476384/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-pause-resume-binders) thread and the spring-cloud-stream [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_binding_visualization_and_control), I injected the BindingsEndpoint and changed the state of the binding like this:

```java
@RestController
public class EventController {
    @Autowired
    public EventController(BindingsEndpoint bindingsEndpoint) {
        this.bindingsEndpoint = bindingsEndpoint;
    }
    @GetMapping("/changeState")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestParam("state") String state) {
        if (state.equals("paused")) {
            bindingsEndpoint.changeState("MY_BINDING", 
                           BindingsEndpoint.State.PAUSED);
        }
        if (state.equals("resumed")) {
            bindingsEndpoint.changeState("MY_BINDING", 
                           BindingsEndpoint.State.RESUMED);
        }
    }
```

This is not exactly what I wanted to achieve but it is close enough.

Comment: This endpoint exists under spring actuator endpoints: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_binding_visualization_and_control

Answer (score -1):

In your code example, I'm not sure what `input.poll` returns, since you assign the result to a `boolean`, and that is not what the `KafkaConsumer.poll` method returns.

A Kafka Consumer can be paused and restarted on demand, that shouldn't be an issue.

From the latest `KafkaConsumer` javadoc:

> **Consumption Flow Control**
>
> ...
>
> Kafka supports dynamic controlling of consumption flows by using **pause(Collection)** and **resume(Collection)** to pause the consumption on the specified assigned partitions and resume the consumption on the specified paused partitions respectively in the future poll(Duration) calls.

And then this from the `pause` method description:

> Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, **it does not cause a group rebalance** when automatic assignment is used.

https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

So in your case, you could simply have a `volatile boolean isPaused` flag, and if that was changed, you'd issue the `pause` or `resume` commands as needed.  The KafkaConsumer will do the rest.

Also, note that that the KafkaConsumer is *not* thread-safe, so you should issue those commands on the same thread that is polling for data.

Comment: You provided an answer to a question that hasn't been asked. That is really confusing and wrong.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky could you please explain why is this answer wrong or confusing?