# Spring-Cloud-Streams Kafka - How to stop the consumers

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring-Cloud-Streams client reading from a Kakfa topic consisting of several partitions. The client calls a webservice for every Kafka message it reads. If the webservice is unavailable after a few retries, I want to stop the consumer from reading from Kafka. Referring to a previous Stackoverflow question ([Spring cloud stream kafka pause/resume binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476384/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-pause-resume-binders)) I autowired **BindingsEndpoint** and call the **changeState()** method to try to stop the consumer but the logs show the consumer continuing to read the messages from Kafka after **changeState()** is invoked.

I am using Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE with Spring Cloud version Greenwich.RELEASE. The managed version for spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka is 2.1.0.RELEASE. I have set the properties autoCommitOffset=true and autoCommitOnError=false.

Below is snippet of my codes. Is there something I have missed? Is the first input parameter to **changeState()** supposed to be the topic name?

If I want the consumer application to exit when the webservice is not available, can I simply do System.exit() without needing to stop the consumer first?

```
@Autowired
private BindingsEndpoint bindingsEndpoint;

...
...
@StreamListener(MyInterface.INPUT)  
    public void read(@Payload MyDTO dto,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        try {

            logger.info("Processing message "+dto);
            process(dto); // this is the method that calls the webservice


        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (e instanceof IllegalStateException || e instanceof ConnectException) {

                bindingsEndpoint.changeState("my.topic.name", 
                    BindingsEndpoint.State.STOPPED);    
                // Binding<?> b = bindingsEndpoint.queryState("my.topic.name"); ==> Using topic name returns a valid Binding object                     
            }

                e.printStackTrace();
                throw (e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by utilising [Binding visualization and control](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control) feature where you can *visualize* as well as *stop/start/pause/resume* bindings.

Also, you are aware that `System.exit()` will shut down the entire JVM?

Comment: Stopping the consumer will only take effect after all the messages received from the last `poll()` have been processed. If you want it to stop immediately, you need to set the kafka consumer property `max.poll.records` to `1`.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, the first input parameter to changeState() should be the binding name. It worked for me