# Spring Cloud Stream PAUSE/RESUME Kafka binders

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In the Spring Cloud Stream application with Kafka binders, I am trying to PAUSE/RESUME the input binders. I searched and all of those sample solutions suggest using `BindingsEndpoint`.
References->

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html

[Spring cloud stream kafka pause/resume binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476384/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-pause-resume-binders)

Using the BindingsEndpoint works in *Spring Integration annotations based configuration*  Is there any way to use this feature in functional-style programming where Kafka listener is `Consumer<T>` bean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it works on functional style as well. There are examples in the documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control

Comment: Great! Thanks, @OlegZhurakousky for sharing the link. Would you recommend using a circuit breaker pattern to conditional STOP / START the Kafka bindings?