# Spring Cloud Stream - Consume Data on Demand manually?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Using Spring Data Stream, How can I start reading from a queue and stop reading on demand?

I want to so something like this:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SomeConsumer {

  @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
  public void receiveMsg(Message<String> message)
  {
    logger.info(" received new message [" + message.toString() + "] ");
  }

  public static void startReceiving()
  {
     //How to implement this logic?
  }

  public static void stopReceiving()
  {
     //How to implement this logic?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done in a static method; autowire the `BindingsEndpoint` and use the `changeState()` method.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795176/stop-consume-message-for-stream-listener).