# How do I start Spring Cloud Stream Binders manually if autoStartup is set to false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` to create a Kafka consumer binding and I've configured `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.autoStartup` to `false`

(https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties).

I want to know what I have to inject at which time to start the binder (for example through a configuration which is enabled by property). I was not able to find any documentation about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `BindingsEndpoint` bean to change the state.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795176/stop-consume-message-for-stream-listener).

Currently, the actuator has to be on the class path.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Wasn't sure if the BindingsEndpoint was the correct Bean because of the actuator reference. It may be useful to mention the BindingsEndpoint class in the docs and reference the BindingsEndpoint in the Doc for the autoStartup property. The ApplicationRunner Interface was important too, with @PostConstruct or something similar in a configuration class the invoction of the BindingsEndpoint would be to early.

Comment: Yes; post construct is too early - there is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1907) to decouple this functionality from the actuator.