# Start Binding in Paused state

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I would like to start my SCS application with the bindings not consuming messages. I use the Kafka binder. Is there any configuration for this?

Alternatively I could use the `BindingsLifecycleController` to programatically pause the bindings. How do I make sure the bindings are already initialized?

Comment: I tried using the `autoStartup=false` property without success. Setting `spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.autoStartup=false` all bindings are stopped. However I would like to have an individual setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these related SO threads:

[How do I start Spring Cloud Stream Binders manually if autoStartup is set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577223/how-do-i-start-spring-cloud-stream-binders-manually-if-autostartup-is-set-to-fal)

[Stop consume message for Stream listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795176/stop-consume-message-for-stream-listener)

Basically, you need to use `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer.autoStartup` and set it to `false` or `true` to individually control it.

If you set that to `false`, then you need to use the `BindingsEndpoint` mechanism described in the above threads to start the binding.