# Programmatic way to read message using spring cloud stream kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a topic and DLQ associated with it. I am using @StreamListener for the topic.
I wanted to read/process the messages from the DLQ on demand using a controller endpoint.

is it possible to do this using spring cloud stream Kafka.

We are not using actuator in production. So can not use /bindings endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to enable the actuators over web, but you need to add the actuator starter to the class path; then you can use the technique in the answer to this question: [Stop consume message for Stream listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795176/stop-consume-message-for-stream-listener)

As noted in the comments there, there is an open issue to separate the functionality from the actuator.