# How to start and stop a google pubsub subsriber in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I have implemented a google pubsub topic-subscriber (spring-boot and cloud stream framework) using the spring.io guides example.

App starts consuming the messages as soon as the app is up. I would like to implement an api where we start and stop the consumption of messages on demand.

Let's say GET /pubsub/messages -> start the subscriber -> gets messages (synchronous or asynchronous) -> stops the subscriber.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer [Stop consume message for Stream listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795176/stop-consume-message-for-stream-listener)

You need to add the actuator Boot starter and inject the `BindingsEndpoint` to stop/start the binding.

You can set `autoStartup` to false to prevent the binding from starting immediately.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, it helped.